# "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong" In Code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Problem Statement:

I created a class for table named it 'groupimages', added migrations successfully, updated database successfully, but table was not showing in database after running these commands in visual studio. then i added new class 'groupimages2' and did the same. again table was not showing in database. i deleted both classes and added again new class 'groupimages3' and run command "add-migration abc", it gives error of 'there are some pending migrations..etc' when i run 'update-database' command. it gives below error

```
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.
```

i am unable to solve my problem. due to this problem i am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by myself. I changed the migration class code and removed the unwanted and exceptional code. run migrations and updated database. It is resolved and working fine.